# Chrome Apps No Longer Opening in Their Own Window

Tags: google-chrome

After a certain Chrome update (around July or so) the Chrome app shortcuts (Gmail, Calendar, Play music) on the unity launcher no longer open in their own window, they open in a tab in the full Chrome browser. Any fixes? I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: [Edit] your question and start the output of `grep -r chrome /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u | tee >(xargs cat)` and the output of `grep -r chrome ~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u | tee >(xargs cat)`

Comment: If you're done, give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to chrome://apps, right-click on the app that you want to open in its own window, and check the "open as window" option.

Comment: @Alex: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.